# SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

got this error while trying to execute a built in command from my ERP system.

[image]

after  goole search i have found that i need to reset the compatibily level of the db schema. is that the right solution? 
and if so - is changing the level can't hurt the DATA ? it's a living and kicking DB

Comment: You probably want to use feature that is not available in SQL Server 2008. Show the code that caused this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DB was upgraded but the COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL parameter was not changed.
If you will change this parameter it will put the new DB version into effect.  It doesn't have any effect on the data, but do it carefully as this is actually the last phase in upgrade process.

***What can go wrong?***

When the DB COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL will changes new features will kick in, this means that the optimiser logic will change and several queries can suffer from performance degradation (if you used weird hints). 
I highly suggest to do this on a test environment first and make sure the apps using the DB are still working.